# Padding between ActionBar's home icon and title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Does anybody know how to set padding between the ActionBar's home icon and the title?

Comment: Welcome to the world of hacks: ***Android***. This simple thing should have been found by anyone (even a newbie) if we need this in other UI techs and application programming. However in Android, it's really mysterious. They ***intentionally*** hide the feature away, make it complicated and just to make Android become ***a world of hacks***. I  don't know what their final purpose is.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917867/space-between-toolbar-icon-and-toolbar-title) and answers give way to achieve this with attributes inside the toolbar (support v7)

Comment: Android sucks even more than iOS.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I adapted Cliffus answer and assigned the logo-drawable in my actionbar style definition, for instance like this in res/style.xml:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#3f51b5</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@drawable/actionbar_space_between_icon_and_title</item>
</style>
```

The drawable looks like Cliffus' one (here with the default app launcher icon) in res/drawable/actionbar_space_between_icon_and_title.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:right="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

In the android_manifest.xml you can still set a different app icon (launcher icon on 'desktop'. Any different logo definition here are visible in activities without an action bar.

Comment: why it doesn\`t take effects on Android 5.1

Comment: Sorry, I can't say something about it in 5.1. I switched to the more flexible Toolbar-Control. If not already done, I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow and write some more details, what worked for you (<5.1) and what does not work and what you tried with 5.1, but didn't come to a solution.

Comment: Thank you @Minsky, i inspired from your answer to resolve my problem, i put how in the answer below :)

Comment: What's if used mipmap?

Answer (score 103):

**EDIT**: make sure you set this drawable as **LOGO**, not as your app icon like some of the commenters did.

Just make an XML drawable and put it in the resource folder "drawable" (without any density or other configuration).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_logo"
        android:right="10dp"/>


</layer-list>
```

The last step is to set this new drawable as logo in your manifest (or on the Actionbar object in your activity)

Good luck!

Comment: The padding added to the image also changes the launcher icon, which is not good at all =/

Comment: This is a great and clean solution! Alesqui - just use a different icon for your launcher and your action bar

Comment: There is a big problem here with this solution. I used it and @Alesqui is right - the app icon changed and became smaller... You could change icon but since dp is different for different phones then this solution doesn't cut it in a production app.

Comment: @dhaag23 to use different icons, the launcher activity cannot have the modified img as icon. So I would have to have a launcher Activity with the unmodified img and then call the Activities with the modified img. And the modified img does not have a margin, but a PADDING instead (which means that the img original icon is forced to reduce horizontally)

Comment: @Alesqui You can make a drawable with a margin like this:

<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/actionBarIcon"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"/>

</layer-list>

Comment: @dhaag23, that's exactly how Cliffus described in his post. But I tested here and the image gets distorted (like a padding behavior would do). So, it didn't work =/

Comment: make sure you are setting this drawable as LOGO, not as your app icon. good luck!

Comment: I'm also seeing distortion. If I apply right padding as above, the right hand side of the image is cropped.

Comment: Smart and robust solution. Does not depend on internals.

Comment: Interesting solution but does not work for me - i can either add extra padding this way or crop the logo image - no good (4.3)

Comment: @Cliffus - nice solution. My requirement was to take the logo to left so I used : android:left="-4dp".

Comment: Works when all else fails!

Comment: if you use logo i think you have to turn it on in the actionbar...setDisplayUseLogoEnabled() Enables the use of an alternative image (a "logo") in the Action Bar, instead of the default application icon. A logo is often a wider, more detailed image that represents the application

Answer (score 55):

I also faced a similar issue, in my case I had to set titles dynamically on each activity depending on the content.

So this worked for me.

```
actionBar.setTitle("  " + yourActivityTitle);
```

If all you want is the spacing, this is the easiest solution I could think of.

Comment: Why the down vote? Don't reckon it's a wrong answer, just another way of doing it.

Comment: This is not a clean way of doing this at all. Yes, it works, but so do table-based layouts in HTML. Ask any web developer, and they'll say table-based layouts are a sign of sloppy/inexperienced coding.

Comment: @idratherbeintheair Yes I agree this isn't the "cleanest" way so now it only says easiest. But when you point out something, please post an alternative solution. I faced this issue and this is what I've used in my app, so I shared.

Comment: Really? This solution might not work the same on different screens with different DPI.

Comment: Not how I'd like to do it :) But it works ! And was the quickest :)

Comment: I'll not choose this solution because I really need sth more stable in my app, but I want to ask all those people saying "It's not clean". Oh, My, God, where is CLEAN solution for this problem? All those hacks with logos, setPadding don't look clean to me either! Just read comments, how many people have problems with those too. Setting android:paddingLeft on title - that what would be CLEAN if it had worked. We are left here in the dark to invent hacks because for some reason it just does not work the way it should have worked. So nothing is "not clean".

Comment: This somehow gives different results to different devices. How would I achieve something like `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Player O: " + "            " + "Player X: ");` with both `Player O` and `Player X` align to left and right of the action bar?

Comment: its a slang solution

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to use the `app:titleMarginStart` attribute in the layout XML.

Answer (score 40):

This is how I was able to set the padding between the home icon and the title.

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

I couldn't find a way to customize this via the ActionBar xml styles though. That is, the following XML doesn't work:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">        
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_home</item>        
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>   <!-- Can't get this padding to work :( -->
</style>
```

However, if you are looking to achieve this through xml, these two links might help you find a solution:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

(This is the actual layout used to display the home icon in an action bar)
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_home.xml

Comment: @Dushyanth i just tried but says null pointer exception on imageview. i have both homeUpIndicator and home icon in action bar.

Comment: This is only working for API >= 11 as android.R.id.home was introduced in API 11. I use actionbarcompat to have an actionbar also on pre honeycomp devices. How to handle it there?

Comment: A little bit of a hack. See Cliffus's answer below for a cleaner solution.

Comment: the home spacing is no longer set using `padding`, it seems to use `marginEnd` since api 17 - which will probably break this solution. See mine below

Comment: @tobias R.id.home is allways there, even before level 11.it just not available

Answer (score 32):

This is a common question in Material Design as you may want to line your toolbars title with the content in the fragment below.  To do this, you can override the default padding of "12dp" by using the attribute **contentInsetStart="72dp"** in your toolbar.xml layout as shown below

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_theme_color"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"/>
```

Then in your activity, call

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Title Goes Here");
```

And you end up with this:

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: This is not at all working in my case. Please let me know the style set to activity

Comment: This is the right way to do this. There is also `app:titleMarginStart="dimension"` to target the title directly.

Comment: Think for most users this will be the "right" answer. Works as a charm, Thanks!

Comment: How is this the "right" answer, if the question was about padding between the home icon and the title? The home icon isn't mentioned here (nor the logo or whatever variation). If `contentInsetStart` puts space between the home icon and the title, the answer could at least say so. My test just now with `contentInsetStart` seemed to put the space *before* the logo (which admittedly is not the same as the home icon).

Answer (score 32):

If you are using toolbar from AppCompat (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, >= revision 24, June 2016), the padding between the icon and the title can be changed with the following value :

```
  app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

To improve my answer, you can use it on your toolbar directly inside your activity or you can create a new layout file for your toolbar. In this case, you just have to import your toolbar's @id using the include property on each needed views.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You can then import your layout on your activity.xml

```
<include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Great.  It would be better if you can provide the sample related XML to clarify where to put this. (I do know where to put this line)

Comment: @JohnPang i detailed my answer, hope it will help you to understand how to use this property.

Comment: @Bolein95 are you uisng the support library ? to be able to help you please provide more information.

Comment: Worth noting that this parameter was introduced in version 24 of the design library. So if you're stuck in eclipse at version 23 (like I used to until yesterday...), you won't have access to it.

Comment: @FloriantT thank you for the precision, i've updated my answer regarding your comment.

Answer (score 30):

For me only the following combination worked, tested from API 18 to 24

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

where in "app" is : `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

for example.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/SE_Life_Green"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                >
                .......
                .......
                .......
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. @Ajit

Comment: Great.  It would be better if you can provide the sample related XML to clarify where to put this. (I do know where to put this line)

Comment: Hello @JohnPang, you can put this in the Toolbar of your layout as shown above.

Answer (score 6):

Using `titleMarginStart` works for me. Xamarin example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  app:titleMarginStart="24dp"/>
```

Set the logo like so:

```
mToolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
SupportActionBar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.titleicon32x32);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.Title = "App title";
```

Answer (score 4):

I used \t before the title and worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Im using a custom image instead of the default title text to the right of my apps logo. This is set up programatically like

```
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.include_ab_txt_logo);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

The issues with the above answers for me are @Cliffus's suggestion does not work for me due to the issues others have outlined in the comments and while @dushyanth programatic padding setting may have worked in the past I would think that the fact that the spacing is now set using `android:layout_marginEnd="8dip"` since API 17 manually setting the padding should have no effect. See the link he posted to git to verify its current state.

A simple solution for me is to set a negative margin on my custom view in the actionBar, like so `android:layout_marginLeft="-14dp"`. A quick test shows it works for me on 2.3.3 and 4.3 using `ActionBarCompat`

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: @Diri can u add more can we make action bar at up ,down,left,right

Comment: @amitsharma - im not sure what you mean exactly - do you mean moving the action bar from the top of the screen? If so I think you would need to create a custom action bar view to do this - it sounds like it may not be good ux though :)

Comment: in that case I dont know what you mean by "can u add more can we make action bar at up ,down,left,right"

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by using custom Navigation layout

Using it you can customize anything in title on action bar:

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    ...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/ActionBar</item>
```

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
   <item name="displayOptions">showCustom</item>
   <item name="android:displayOptions" tools:ignore="NewApi">showCustom</item>

    <item name="customNavigationLayout">@layout/action_bar</item>
   <item name="android:customNavigationLayout" tools:ignore="NewApi">@layout/action_bar</item>

    <item name="background">@color/android:white</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/android:white</item>
```

action_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:drawablePadding="10dp"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:text="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with spacing between the up and the custom app icon/logo in the action bar. Dushyanth's solution of setting padding programatically worked for me (setting padding on app/logo icon). I tried to find either **android.R.id.home** or **R.id.abs__home** (**ActionBarSherlock only**, as this ensures backwards compatibility), and it seems to work across 2.3-4.3 devices I've tested on.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was with Toolbar i resolved it like this:

ic_toolbar_drawble.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_toolbar"
    android:right="-16dp"
    android:left="-16dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

In my Fragment, i check the api :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
else
      toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar_draweble);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can change drawableSize of your DrawerArrow like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.WithActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="barLength">24dp</item>
    <item name="arrowShaftLength">24dp</item>
    <item name="arrowHeadLength">10dp</item>
    <item name="drawableSize">42dp</item> //this is your answer
</style>
```

It isn't correct answer, because you can't choose padding side and DrawerArrow icon scaling when change drawableSize (drawableSize = width = height). But you can margin from left. To margin from right do

```
findViewById(android.R.id.home).setPadding(10, 0, 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method `setContentInsetsAbsolute(int contentInsetLeft, int contentInsetRight)` and it works!

```
int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_content_insets);
mToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(padding, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a custom Toolbar, you can use

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

and in your toolbar layout simply set `app:titleMarginStart="16dp"`

Note that you have to set the icon as a logo, don't use `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo)`
instead use:
`getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo)`

Answer (score 0):

I used `AppBarLayout` and custom `ImageButton` do to so.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="32dp"
           android:layout_height="32dp"
           android:src="@drawable/selector_back_button"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
           android:id="@+id/back_button"/>

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </RelativeLayout>    
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My Java code:

```
findViewById(R.id.appbar).bringToFront();
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same by method as well:

```
Drawable d = new InsetDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_icon),0,0,10,0);
mToolbar.setLogo(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, set the `app:titleMargin` in your Toolbar view as following:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleMarginStart="16dp"/>
```

Or in your code:

```
toolbar.setTitleMargin(16,16,16,16); // start, top, end, bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include:

```
    app:titleMargin="10dp"
```

Within your xml file, like:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbrMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleMargin="10dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that for my project minSdk is 21 and I wanted to modify the original action bar (not create a custom toolbar), none of these other answers worked.

-- TLDR start: Set the logo-title space to match the action bar-logo space --

In my theme, I used the following:

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/Theme.AppName.ActionBar</item>
```

Caution: Using `actionBarStyle` always broke most if not all properties.

Also in themes.xml:

```
<style
    name="Theme.AppName.ActionBar"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">

    <item name="icon">@drawable/baseline_wb_sunny_24</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    <item name="titleMarginStart">0dp</item>

</style>
```

Java activity:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
assert actionBar != null;
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

// Match the title padding to the action bar inset
final View actionBarView = this.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
final ViewGroup actionBarViewGroup = (ViewGroup) actionBarView;
for (int i = 0; i < actionBarViewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View actionBarChildView = actionBarViewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if (actionBarChildView instanceof AppCompatTextView) {
        final AppCompatTextView titleView = (AppCompatTextView) actionBarChildView;
        titleView.setPadding(((Toolbar) actionBarView).getContentInsetStart(), 0, 0, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

-- TLDR end --

Above, I set `titleMarginStart` to 0dp. The default value is 4(?)dp (or 8 pixels on my device), found by using the Java tools below. Through trial and error, I noticed that the first 12dp of `titleMarginStart` are ignored and are the same as 0dp. I managed to get an instance of the action bar's toolbar and according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar?hl=en#getTitleMarginStart()) `getTitleMarginStart` and `setTitleMarginStart` were added in API 24. It seems that this value was buggy before 24. So in my solution, just to be sure, I set it to 0dp (XML or Java).

Then, enable the icon and title. Finally, get `R.id.action_bar` (this value is NOT suggested/autocompleted by Android Studio so I created and used the tools below), loop through its children, target the view that you wish to modify and have at it.

In API 21, neither `android.R.id.home` nor `R.id.home` worked.

-- Tools --

Find the root view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);

    final ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    View rootView = this.findViewById(R.id.any_known_view_id);
    while (rootView.getParent() != null) {
        rootView = (View) rootView.getParent();
        Log.d("whatever", "rootView class: " + rootView.getClass().getName());
    }

    this.logChildren(rootView);
}
```

Log children:

```
private int depth = 0;

private void logChildren(View view) {
    final ViewParent vp = view.getParent();
    if (vp != null) {
        if (view instanceof Toolbar && vp instanceof ActionBarContainer) {
            Log.d("whatever", "toolbar id: " + view.getId());
            Log.d("whatever", "toolbar id: " + view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId()));
            // com.example.appname:id/action_bar
            Log.d("whatever", "toolbar id: " + this.findViewById(R.id.action_bar).getId());
            final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view;
            Log.d("whatever", "toolbar inset start: " + toolbar.getContentInsetStart());
            Log.d("whatever", "toolbar inset end: " + toolbar.getContentInsetEnd());
            Log.d("whatever", "title margin start: " + toolbar.getTitleMarginStart());
        }

        // Experiment: Set the paddings of ActionBarContextView to 0
        if (view instanceof ActionBarContextView && vp instanceof ActionBarContainer) {
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        // Experiment: Set the paddings of AppCompatTextView (the title!!)
        if (view instanceof AppCompatTextView && vp instanceof Toolbar) {
            view.setPadding(70, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        // Experiment: Get the logo/icon dimensions
        if (view instanceof AppCompatImageView && vp instanceof Toolbar) {
            Log.d("whatever", "image width: " + view.getMeasuredWidth());
            Log.d("whatever", "image height: " + view.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    Log.d("whatever", "depth " + this.depth + ": " + className);
    Log.d("whatever", "paddings " + view.getPaddingTop() + ", " + view.getPaddingRight() + ", " + view.getPaddingBottom() + ", " + view.getPaddingLeft());

    if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
        return;
    }

    this.depth++;

    final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;

    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        this.logChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
    }
    this.depth--;
}
```

Note that the obtained values above are in pixels and not dp.

Once you have the objects/classes and the structure of the action bar, use [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar) to find info on methods and XML properties. (Check super classes too.)

Do not assume that there's top/bottom padding in the action bar. It could have a fixed height and vertically center its contents.

Answer (score -2):

this work for me to add padding to the title and for `ActionBar` icon i have set that programmatically.

```
 getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fffff'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Boat App </font>"));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<string name="app_name">"    "Brick Industry</string>
```

Just add `"   "` for your app name 
It will add space between icon and title

Comment: This is not bad, i dont know why it got so downvoted

Comment: maybe sometimes the simplest of the solution is the best! thanks