# Android Home As Up Indicator filename or location

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable, android-assets

Where do I find the Android "Up" button drawable so that I can customize it? Or what is its filename, so that I can do a quick search to locate it within a sdk directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in [default style](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) (at the end), `ActionBar` style uses this:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@android:drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

You can find the [layout resource](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_home.xml) used to display the *Up* and *App icon* on your ActionBar. 
The positioning of these elements (*Up* and *App icon*) are hard-coded into the layout resources, it might be difficult to change or customize it.. However, you didn't explain a lot, so I'll try to answer on possible customizations.

You can customize the *Up indicator* in your style and put your own icon as follows:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

*Note: it must be in the parent style, not in ActionBar's style.*

Then, if you want to resize the padding between *Up* and *icon*, you have these solutions:

> 1. Create a **custom view** and hide the built home navigation ([see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750956/2668136)).
> 2. Change it with **setPadding** [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735271/2668136) (however, this have to be used on each activity, and it's a bit messy).
> 3. Use a **drawable layer-list** and replace the homeAsUpIndicator theme ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600026/2668136)).

Finally, you can get this icon on [Android Drawable's website](http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html) and also in [/res/drawable-xxx](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi) named `ic_ab_back_holo_light_am.png` and `ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png`.

**UPDATE:**
And since MaterialDesign, you can find this icon on [Material Design Icons](http://materialdesignicons.com/) named "arrow-left".

I hope this will be useful.