# android : padding for homeupindicator in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add padding to the left of the "home up " left arrow in actionbar. I could add padding between the home icon and the title . Is it possible to add space to the left of home button than using drawable resource with padding

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom layout for Actionbar(Toolbar) and insert all change what you want. Or you can operate only one view, example : [Padding the actionbar "up" indicator image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706975/padding-the-actionbar-up-indicator-image)