# Icon padding in actionbarsherlock

Tags: icons, actionbarsherlock, padding

I use actionbarsherlock in my app and the icon on it isn't displayed as I want. How can I change paddings of the icon? I want the image to reach top bottom and left.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360503/807434)

> Just make an XML drawable and put it in the resource folder "drawable" (without any density or other configuration).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_logo"
        android:right="10dp"/>


</layer-list>
```

> The last step is to set this new drawable as logo in your manifest (or
>   on the Actionbar object in your activity)

Comment: Thanks, I guess it works, but not on my device. Sony Xperia U - something weird is happening there))