# Android Navigation Drawer left margin

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to set left margin for Navigation Drawer, like in new play market.
[image]

I use ActionBarDrawerToggle from android.support.v7, but I can't make margin in the left on drawer indicator. 
[image]

Is it possible?

**Update:**
Yes, with toolbar widget I see margins. But I have another problem: This is Navigation Drawer in white color

[image]

But when I use

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

I see back icon in black

[image]

Can I make back button white programmatically? Or use custom icon only?

Comment: the easiest way to do it is using a transparency within the drawable.. also this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10120562/1084764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, they have used toolbar instead of action bar. In playstore as well as play music. in toolbar, it can be customized, but in actionbar, its place is by default there.