# Android actionBar + padding on set Logo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using an action bar and I would like to set my Logo to the left is there any way I can implement padding to the left or left align with the below statement

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_deviceLogo);
```

Comment: Please find the well-written answer here [Padding between ActionBar's home icon and title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737101/padding-between-actionbars-home-icon-and-title)